# Reading PSV (pipe-separated) file or string

Tags: r, csv, file-io, pipe, file-format

I have just received a data file, whose extension is "*.psv". After doing a bit of research, I don't know how to open it R.

Comment: a snippet of the data would be helpful. if it's a "pipe separated" file, then `sep="|"` to `read.csv` or `read.table` would do it.

Comment: open the file using notepad to eyeball the data and see what the separating character is

Comment: The Intarwebz say PSV could be pipe-separated (easy to deal with),  PlayStationSave (who knows)  or Pipe System Viewer (probably need a special reader).   Where did you get the file from?

Comment: Hi, I think the file is pipe separated and read.csv() with sep = "|" works. Thanks very much

Comment: @DuyBui, please post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: `read.csv()` is not just for files, it can equally parse textConnections too. Retitling this *"Read PSV format"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We could use read.table to read *.psv file.

```
read.table("myfile.psv", sep = "|", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There might be many different representations of psv file, but when it comes to data mining, I think it might be more about "pipe separated" file. The data in the file is separated by "|"