# Dealing with bigger comments in R that forms a new line while importing

Tags: r, comments, multiline, file-import

I want to import a txt file in R studio to clean it up. While importing I am using readr's read_delim because it is a pipe seperated file (|). However, the problem is that some data is entered on a new line even though it belongs to the same row. The row number are at the end of the line in the very last column.

Here is the sample of .txt version:

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|ROW NUMBER
SF|SDF|DVN|||FDH|FHJ|1
AF|DFG|AD||AGF|SD|V|2
SDG|DSG|DFSG
DFGSG: FSDG                        3453 
SDFG SFDG SDG
SDF GDGS HSHS 
DG FSD HJHS A GR DG 
DSGF DG SD G|||SDT|SDFG|3
```

There is a big comment in one of the column which R thinks is a new line and adds it accordingly

This is what I get when importing:

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKthC.jpg)

The question is that how can I make sure that the big comment does not form a new row? I have tried using removing whitespace, setting column orders so that the number column appears first but no luck yet.

Comment: Your example is unclear. Which is the big comment which R thinks is a new line? Which line number, which column number? Did you mean you want "DFGSG : FSDG                        3453" treated as column A? Also **please post your import code**. You don't *need* to use `readr::read_delim()` on PSV, you can try using `read.csv(..., sep='|')`

Comment: Related and possibly duplicate: [Reading PSV (pipe-separated) file or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966203/reading-psv-pipe-separated-file-or-string)

Comment: See also [read.csv multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read.csv+multiline+is%3Aq) questions

Comment: So the very first row is a header. So, I want **DFGSG: FSDG  3453  to DSFG DG SD G** in one line in column A. In the .txt file, it is written in new line as shown above but I want it in one row just in column A before it reaches pipe to identify the end of the column.

Comment: Right so the term for this is "multiline comment"